# Mean residual lifetime divided by odds of survival?

Tags: survival, odds

Is there a name for the mean residual lifetime divided by odds of survival? Does it have an intuitive meaning or interpretation?

Example:

$P(X=\{0,1,2,3\}) = (0.40, 0.30, 0.2, 0.1)$

$E[X-1|X>=1]=\frac{(.3*1+.2*2+.1*3)}{(1-.4)} - 1 = 2/3$

$Odds(P(X>=1)) = \frac{.3+.2+.1}{.4} = 3/2$

$Ratio = \frac{2/3}{3/2} = 4/9$

Alternatively it can be thought of as the product of the mean residual lifetime and odds of death

$Odds(P(X<1)) = \frac{.4}{1-.4} = 2/3$

$Product = (2/3)*(2/3) = 4/9$